# Master detail page Loading menu entries MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using MVVM and i have master detail where i have 9 entries plus some if statements to display the correct entry if user is logged in or not., but loading all of this takes quite long time is there some other way to speed up the process? I am adding the loading method with the if statements so you can see that it does take a while only loading the menu entries. Also i added the selection method

```
     public void LoadData()
            {
                MainMenuEntries = new ObservableCollection<MenuEntry>();

                if (LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedIn)
                {

                    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                    {

                        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryUserProfile,
                        Icon = GrialIconsFont.User,
                        CreatePage = () => new UserProfile()

                    });
                }
                else if (LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedOffline)
                {
                    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                    {
                        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryUserProfile,
                        Icon = GrialIconsFont.User,
                        CreatePage = () => new UserProfile()

                    });

                }
                else
                {
                    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                    {
                        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryLoginSignUp,
                        Icon = GrialIconsFont.User,
                        CreatePage = () => new Login()
                    });

                }

                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategorySettings,
                    Icon = GrialIconsFont.Settings,
                    CreatePage = () => new Settings()

                });
                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryHelp,
                    Icon = GrialIconsFont.AlertInfo,
                    CreatePage = () => new Help()
                });
                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryCredits,
                    Icon = GrialIconsFont.Box,

                    CreatePage = () => new Credits()
                });
                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryPromo,
                    Icon = GrialIconsFont.Hashtag,
                    CreatePage = () => new Promo()
                });

                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryPickYourTheme,
                    HasSeparator = true,
                    Icon = GrialIconsFont.Fire,
                    CreatePage = () => new PickYourTheme()
                });

                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryArticlesForPurchase,
                    Icon = GrialIconsFont.ShoppingCart,
                    CreatePage = () => new TabMenuArticlesForPurchase()
                });
                if (LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedIn || LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedOffline)
                {
                    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                    {
                        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryMyArticles,
                        Icon = GrialIconsFont.File,
                        CreatePage = () => new TabMenuMyArticles()
                    });

                }

                else
                {
                    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                    {
                        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryMyArticles,
                        Icon = GrialIconsFont.File,
                        CreatePage = () => new Login()
                    });
                }
                if (LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedIn || LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedOffline)
                {
                    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                    {
                        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryDictionary,
                        Icon = GrialIconsFont.Book,
                        CreatePage = () => new Dictionary()
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                    {
                        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryDictionary,
                        Icon = GrialIconsFont.Book,
                        CreatePage = () => new Login()
                    });
                }

                MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
                {
                    Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryArticles,
                    Icon = GrialIconsFont.File,
                    CreatePage = () => new ArticleBrowser()
                });
            }

public MenuEntry MainMenuSelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedMainMenuEntry; }
            set
            {
                if (SetProperty(ref _selectedMainMenuEntry, value) && value != null)
                {
                    Page page;

                    if (value.PageType != null)
                    {
                        page = CreatePage(value.PageType);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        page = value.CreatePage();
                    }

                    NavigationPage navigationPage;

                    if (value.NavigationPageType == null)
                    {
                        navigationPage = new NavigationPage(page);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        navigationPage = (NavigationPage)Activator.CreateInstance(value.NavigationPageType, page);
                    }

                    if (value.UseTransparentNavBar)
                    {
                        GrialNavigationPage.SetIsBarTransparent(navigationPage, true);
                    }

                    if (_selectedMainMenuEntry.IsModal)
                    {
                        _navigation.PushModalAsync(navigationPage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _openPageAsRoot(navigationPage);
                    }

                    _selectedMainMenuEntry = null;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(MainMenuSelectedItem));
                }
            }
```

Comment: why are you creating instances of all of your pages just to populate a menu?  It would be much more efficient to create the pages when the user selects the menu option

Comment: how to do that? can you please just share an example

Comment: @Jason ok i did that still quite slow, do you please have any other suggestions?

Comment: you need to do some profiling to figure out what specifically is causing it to be slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't** create a new page every time you add a new `MenuEntry`.

You can follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page#creating-the-master-page) to add a `TargetType` and create the page when you want to use it:

```
    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
    {

        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryUserProfile,
        Icon = GrialIconsFont.User,
        TargetType = typeof(UserProfile)
    });

    MainMenuEntries.Add(new MenuEntry
    {

        Name = AppResources.A_StringCategoryUserProfile,
        Icon = GrialIconsFont.User,
        TargetType = typeof(Login)
    });
```

And in your viewModel:

```
  navigationPage = (NavigationPage)Activator.CreateInstance(value.TargetType);
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-masterdetailpage/) is the sample project you can follow.

And in your first if-else statement:

It looks like the same when `LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedIn` and `LangUpLoggedUser.LoggedOffline`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a binding component in xaml and load the display model only once and not one at a time. The component can be a listview.

>

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                <Button Command="{Binding Command}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

And in ViewModel, you add this (You can add a range ):

>

```
//Property
private List<MenuItem> menuItems

public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }    
    {
        get { return menuItems; }
        set
        {
            MenuItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MenuItems");
        }
    }

MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
            MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem()
            {
                Description = AppResources.MySafetyStartsHere,
                Command = new DelegateCommand(() => { })
            });
```

The Model:

>

```
public class MenuItem
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    }
```